# Can you send data from a Python file to HTML without some sort of framework?

Tags: python, html, api

I'm taking user input from an HTML page and sending it to a Python file to make an API call with the data. I want to take the API response and send it back to an HTML page to be displayed. Is there some way of doing this without implementing some sort of framework like Django or Flask?

**index.html**

```
<form action="/weather.py" method="GET">
     <label for="city">City:</label>
     <input type="text" id="city">
     <input type="submit" value="Generate Playlist!">
</form>
```

**weather.py**

```
import os
import requests
import cgi

key = os.environ.get('WEATHER_KEY')
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
city =  form.getvalue('searchbox')

get_weather()

def get_weather():
    query = {'q': city + ',US', 'units': 'imperial', 'appid': key}
    url = 'api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather'
    try:
        data = requests.get(url, params=query).json()
        forecast = data['list']
    except KeyError:
        print(f'KeyError: Please check city name and country code in {query}')
        return 'Error! Please check city name and country code.', 0, 0, 0
    weather = forecast[0]
    description = weather['weather'][0]['description']
    temperature = weather['main']['temp']
    cloudy = weather['clouds']['all']
    humidity = weather['main']['humidity']
    description = description.capitalize()
```

I know how to do with with Django, but I don't really need any of the other Django functionality so I'm trying to keep super simple if at all possible.

Comment: Do you have to do the get_weather() call in Python?
You could access the API using jquery or javascript an do it all in the front-end if you want to avoid using a backend framework like Flask or Django.

Comment: No, i don’t necessarily need to do it in the get_weather() function. I’m not opposed to trying it with javascript or something, i’ve just never worked with it before. I’ll look into it!